# callback on write to file success, C

Tags: c, operating-system, debian, filesystems

Trying my hand at writing some C scripts, I have some code that should save a string to a file before rebooting the system. Both work separately but trying to write to file immediately before rebooting fails...

```
int writeToConfFile(char* filename, char* newConf) {

  FILE *fp;
  int status;

  fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  fprintf(fp,"%s",&newConf[0]);
  status = fclose(fp);
  return status;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char extraString[1024];
  strcpy(extraString,"0");
  writeToConfFile("/etc/filename", extraString);  
  reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
}
```

adding `sleep(10)` between `writeToConfFile` and `reboot` does the trick, but I would like to do it in a neater way.

edit: the os is a heavily customized legacy debian.

edit2: tried changing `writeToConfFile` to end like this:

```
  fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  fprintf(fp,"%s",&newConf[0]);
  fflush(fp);
  status = fclose(fp);
  return status;
```

but it didn't work either

Comment: Maybe with some [`sync`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync)?

Comment: The code you are showing us is perfectly synchronous, if you cant reboot right after writing to a file it must be something OS related, not in your responsibility.

Comment: You'd have to `fflush` before `fclose`. And try `fsync(fileno(f))` instead of `fflush`. `fflush` flushes stdio buffers, `fsync` has a better chance of making it to disk. Also, check the return values and note errors.

Comment: @jamieguinan thank you, it didn't work, but I have edited the question to have code that makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212012/mathieu) and [jamieguinan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488095/jamieguinan) suggested, calling sync() before reboot makes sure changes are written to disk
so the code ends thus:

```
writeToConfFile("/etc/filename", extraString);  
sync();
reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
```